# Kotlin, Alarm Manager Doesn't Trigger

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I've tried many examples, including the one at Android docs, of course, but none of them worked.

Here is my code:

```
package wentaas.odaklan

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.text.Layout
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
import android.view.View.VISIBLE
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat
import android.content.Intent.makeRestartActivityTask
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.PowerManager
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import android.widget.*
import java.util.*

//fun makeAlarms(context: Context) {
//    val t = TinyDB(context)
//    val hour = t.getListInt("hour")
//    val minute = t.getListInt("minute")
//
//    Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, "$hour\n$minute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//
//    var i = 0
//    for (item in hour) {
//        val alarmMgr = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
//        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).let { intent ->
//            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
//        }
//
//        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent)
//
//        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
//            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
//            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour[i])
//            set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute[i])
//        }
//        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent)
//
//        i += 1
//    }
//}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
//
//        val t = TinyDB(this)
//        t.clear()
//        val is24 = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)
//        var hour = t.getListInt("hour")
//        var minute = t.getListInt("minute")
//
        val am = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val date = Date()
        val alarmCal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val nowCal = Calendar.getInstance()
        nowCal.time = date
        alarmCal.time = date
        alarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10)
        alarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55)
        alarmCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCal.timeInMillis, 1000*60, pendingIntent)
//
//        fun put() {
//            t.putListInt("hour", hour)
//            t.putListInt("minute", minute)
//        }
//
//        if (hour.isEmpty() || minute.isEmpty()) {
//            hour.clear()
//            minute.clear()
//            hour.add(10)
//            minute.add(30)
//            put()
//        }
//
//        fun toText(hour: Int, minute: Int): String {
//            if (is24) {
//                val hourText = when (hour) {
//                    in 0..9 -> "0$hour"
//                    else -> "$hour"
//                }
//                val minuteText = when (minute) {
//                    in 0..9 -> "0$minute"
//                    else -> "$minute"
//                }
//                return "$hourText:$minuteText"
//            } else {
//                val hourText: String
//                val ampm: String
//                when (hour) {
//                    0 -> {
//                        hourText = "12"
//                        ampm = "AM"
//                    }
//                    in 1..9 -> {
//                        hourText = "0$hour"
//                        ampm = "AM"
//                    }
//                    in 10..12 -> {
//                        hourText = "$hour"
//                        ampm = "AM"
//                    }
//                    in 13..23 -> {
//                        hourText = "${hour - 12}"
//                        ampm = "PM"
//                    }
//                    else -> {
//                        hourText = "$hour"
//                        ampm = "AM"
//                    }
//                }
//                val minuteText = when (minute) {
//                    in 0..9 -> "0$minute"
//                    else -> "$minute"
//                }
//                return "$hourText:$minuteText $ampm"
//            }
//        }
//
//        fun load() {
//
//            hour = t.getListInt("hour")
//            minute = t.getListInt("minute")
//            val time = mutableListOf<Button>()
//
//            for (item in layout.touchables) {
//                layout.removeView(item)
//            }
//
//            var i = 0
//            for (item in hour) {
//                val button = Button(this)
//
//                button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30F)
//                val p = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
//                p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
//                button.layoutParams = p
//                button.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
//
//                time.add(button)
//                layout.addView(button)
//
//                i += 1
//            }
//
//            makeAlarms(this)
//
//
//            text.text = "$hour\n$minute\n$time\n${t.getListInt("hour")}\n${t.getListInt("minute")}"
//
//            i = 0
//            for (item in time) {
//                time[i].text = toText(hour[i], minute[i])
//                time[i].setOnClickListener {
//                    val w = time.indexOf(it)
//
//                    val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
//                        this@MainActivity, R.style.CustomDatePickerDialog,
//                        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {_, sHour, sMinute ->
//                            hour[w] = sHour
//                            minute[w] = sMinute
//
//                            put()
//                            load()
//                        }, hour[w], minute[w], is24)
//                    timePickerDialog.show()
//
//                    val deleteButton = timePickerDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL)
//                    deleteButton.text = getString(R.string.delete)
//                    if (w == 0) {
//                        deleteButton.isEnabled = false
//                    }
//                    deleteButton.visibility = VISIBLE
//                    deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
//                        hour.removeAt(w)
//                        minute.removeAt(w)
//
//                        put()
//                        timePickerDialog.dismiss()
//                        load()
//                    }
//                }
//                i += 1
//            }
//        }
//
//        fab.setOnClickListener {
//            val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
//                this@MainActivity, R.style.CustomDatePickerDialog,
//                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {_, sHour, sMinute ->
//                    hour.add(sHour)
//                    minute.add(sMinute)
//
//                    put()
//                    load()
//                }, hour.last(), minute.last(), is24)
//            timePickerDialog.show()
//        }
//
////        load()
//    }
//}
//
//class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
//
//    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
//        if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
//            makeAlarms(context)
//        }
    }
}
//
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context:Context, intent:Intent) {

        val pm = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "1:")

        wl.acquire(10*60*1000L)

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        wl.release()
//
//        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
//            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
//            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.title))
//            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.text))
//
//        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(1, builder.build())
    }
}
```

I've included the comments if they matter at all. It doesn't give any errors, it just doesn't trigger. I've tried this code from 10:53 to 10:56.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="wentaas.odaklan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"-->
                  <!--android:enabled="true">-->
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">-->

                <!--</action>-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        <!--</receiver>-->
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance. Any help would be really appreciated. I'm going nuts on this!

Comment: What device model are you using ? is it xiaomi ?

Comment: I'm using Android Emulator with a custom profile.